# Displying Outlook message from JavaScript add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing end-to-end encryption for email messages with OWA and JavaScript.
When the message arrive to the recipient it has to be decrypted when clicked (or on arrival, whatever).

What is the event on clicking the message?
I can do decryption on onClick event of custom made button on the ribbon. However I need to decrypt the message when clicked in order user to have better experience.
Thanks.

Comment: I have one more question in the context of my email encryption project.
We are using asymmetric encryption so we need to keep private key with OWA on the device of user. Is that possible?
If not, what other other options we have with OWA?
I know we can do that with COM add-ins but we must do that with OWA in order to be cross platform.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Office.js add-ins can only be invoked by the end user after the message is loaded, there are no such events for message onload nor onclick. The message will have to be decrypted via an add-in command button click like you suggested.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Comment: What is the road map regarding invoking add-ins on message onload or onclick events?

Comment: Currently, we have no plans for the feature you requested. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.